# D3D11 : Rotating Multiple Triangles

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am new to DirectX, and I have a bit of a problem understanding some of the basics I think.  Let's say that I have 10 triangles, and I want to rotate each of them at a different rate so that they 'spin' as time goes by.

So far I have my triangles appearing, but I don't quite get how to rotate them individually.  From what I can tell I would do something like this per triangle ?

1. Compute the rotation matrix, and set it in the constant data.
2. Update the constant buffer with the constant data.
3. Update the vertex shader with said data.
4. DrawPrimitives so that my triangle appears on the screen rotated according to the matrix in step #1. (via the vertex shader)

Is that right?  It seems like a lot of back and forth.  Am I supposed to rely on the vertex shader to do the transform, or is there a different way to apply the rotation on a per 'object' (triangle) basis ?

I apologize if my question doesn't make sense, like I said, I think I am having a conceptual / understanding issue.

Comment: Yes you need to set the "world" transform matrix into a constant buffer and use it in the vertex shader to transform each vertex to the new position.

Comment: I think your way was correct. that was based on per 'object' also. you can make a for loop, and do these steps for each triangle.

Comment: @zdd OK, so there isn't some large performance hit for doing all of these one by one?  I was under the impression that doing things (like draw operations) in batches was the way to go, and doing it piecemeal (one at a time) would tank performance / framerate, etc.  Of course this is based on what I remember from the DX9 days...

Comment: @A.R. I don't think there is performance issue. that's the common way to render multiple different objects. if you want to render multiple same object(same mesh, different color or position), you can use [instancing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173349(VS.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: @zdd Alright, that makes sense to me now.  Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have some models (triangles in your case).

Models are arrays of vertices:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float3 position;
    float3 normal;
    float2 texcoord;
    float4 color;
    // other vertex attributes goes here
};
```

You create vertex (and index) buffer(s) once, on initialization.

```
std::vector<Vertex> vertices = { /*vertex data goes here*/ };
VertexBuffer vb = renderer->CreateVertexBuffer(&vertices[0], vertices.size());
```

Your 3D world is an array of **objects** which are **instances** of your model(s).

```
struct MyObject
{
    float3 position;
    float3 rotation;
    float3 scale;
    // other instance attributes goes here (it can be whatever you want)
};

std::vector<MyObject> objects = { /*objects data goes here*/ };
```

Basically object's attributes is a *modifiers* of vertex attributes, so all objects have same model, but looks different in your world (in this example they have different positions).

Position (and also normal, tangent and bitangent) of each vertex typically defined in model space. To move it (transform) to world space you multiply `position` of each vertex by matrix of current object. You don't want to do it on CPU, because it is very slow. **Vertex buffer remains unchanged** (of course, you can change it, to achieve effect of deformation, tessellation, etc., but this is not our case).

So, you do transforms in vertex(or geometry) shader . And you must, somehow, send information of current object's transforms (and other instance attributes) to vertex shader.

**One way is constant buffer(s)**.

Assume you have cbuffer in vertex shader:

```
cbuffer Instance
{
    matrix worldMatrix;
// other instance parameters goes here
};
```

And you must fill it with data.

Before drawing each object, you updating buffer with current *instance data* (once per object (multiple times per frame)):

```
renderer->SetVertexBuffer(vb); // Set needed geometry 
for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) // for each object
{
    matrix worldMatrix = CalculateWorldMatrix(objects[i]); // prepare data of current object
    renderer->UpdateConstantBuffer(&worldMatrix); // Tell shaders about current object's attributes (world matrix in our case)
    renderer->Draw(); // or DrawIndexed();
}
```

For `n` objects you have `n` draw calls and `n` buffer updates.

**Another way is instance buffer(s)**.

You create one more *vertex buffer* which holds not vertex data, but instance data, prepared to be consumed by shader.

You calculate instance data and create instance buffer once:

```
for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) // for each object
{
    std::vector<Instance> instances;
    instances[i].worldMatrix = CalculateWorldMatrix(objects[i]);
    // other instance parameters goes here
}

VertexBuffer instanceBuffer = renderer->CreateVertexBuffer(&instances[0], instances.size());
```

And you must also change input layout, so shader will expect instance data in addition to vertex data.

When drawing, you just bind both vertex and instance buffer. No buffer update needed (if your triangles have not been moved). And no matrix calculation needed any more. So, no `for` loop, and only one (!) draw call.

```
    renderer->SetVertexBuffers(2, vb, instanceBuffer); // Set needed model data and instances data
    renderer->DrawInstanced(); // or DrawIndexedInstanced();
```

You only update instance buffer if you objects changing their parameters: position, color, etc.

When drawing complex scenes, you most times use both: constant buffers (for attributes shared for all or many objects: view matrix, projection matrix, etc.) and instancing (if you have objects with same model geometry, but different attributes), to take their advantages.

Comment: What are the main differences, i.e. pros and cons of the two methods that you have presented here?

Comment: What would be the code that goes into UpdateBuffer?  This seems like it would be a good thing to know.